# Куда смотреть? (апи постинг в группе)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Ребят прошу помощи, так как не могу понять как реализовать постинг на стене в группе..

Как делать посты в группе с сервера стороннего, перечитал всю документацию в вк, но чего то мне не хватает, какой то детали, потому что ничего не работает и вообще...

Нужно приложение делать стандалон что ли??

Я наивно полагая, что все легко и просто, пробежавшись по документации и найдя подходящее описание, решил отправить запрос с сервера следующего содержания

```
file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-."$id_group".&message=."$message".&from_group=1&access_token=."$token".&v=5.60");
```

И конечно же ничего не получилось, потому что этот метод вообще не для групп...

Поискав в методах group. ничего подобного я не нашел.. и совсем потерялся, начал искать  инфу, нашел про то что надо делать через приложение..

в общем объясните мне недалекому КАК это вообще работает, где об этом узнать больше и вообще покажите правильный курс

Огромное человеческое спасибо!

Comment: Документация (равно как и API) у ВК действительно отвратительная, в прочем, это не обязывает кого-либо переписывать её своими словами в виде ответа на ваш вопрос. `потому что ничего не работает` - что не работает? Покажите нам код, даже если он не работает, а там вам, может быть, подскажут, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: @terron,  да я это прекрасно понимаю, мне бы просто в общих чертах, какие методы с какой стороны зайти.. не работает wall.post и как я понял он и не должен там работать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужно приложение делать стандалон что ли??

Да. Пользоваться методом [wall.post](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post) со стороны сервера могут только приложения типа standalone.

> Я наивно полагая, что все легко и просто, пробежавшись по документации и найдя подходящее описание, решил отправить запрос с сервера следующего содержания

С самим запросом к API у вас все в порядке, просто у вас опечатка в коде. Ваш код:

```
file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-."$id_group".&message=."$message".&from_group=1&access_token=."$token".&v=5.60");
```

А должно быть так:

```
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-' . $id_group . '&message=' . $message . '&from_group=1&access_token=' . $token . '&v=5.60');
```

Вы точки засунули внутрь строки, поэтому они участвовали не как оператор конкатенации, а как просто символ "точка".

Но рекомендуется использовать функцию [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php) для построения query-строки, т.к. это выглядит более элегантно и она делает URL-кодирование символов:

```
$parameters = http_build_query([
    'owner_id'     => -$id_group,
    'message'      => $message,
    'from_group'   => 1,
    'access_token' => $token,
    'v'            => '5.60',
]);

$request = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?' . $parameters);
```

Но вместо функции [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) лучше использовать библиотеку [cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php) (чем-то похожа на jQuery AJAX по настройкам). Но если копать еще глубже, то, как по мне, верх удобства и продуктивности - это клиент [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

Comment: Вот готовая обертка для API Vk https://github.com/vladkens/VK